# Rest-API Server in java

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, java-server

so by now I pretty much know everything about Java SE other then networking and when I say networking I mean connecting to clients or connecting to Web APIs like Weather API or something. I have scraped youtube and wiki but haven't find anything that properly explain how I should start.I know that I need to learn Java EE, but there are these scary frameworks like Spring, Maven, Gradle, Spring Boot etc.

The idea here that I want to make a server in java for my front-end that I currently have in Node.js where I use express to communicate with the client. Now I need to know the frameworks I should learn to the exact thing I could do with express but in java. (Please don't to recommend since stack-overflow folks don't like recommending, just explain what each framework do. Thanks)

Comment: Spring is scary, unless you are building a huge thing, I'd learn python instead, that might be faster.

Comment: U dont need any frameworks technically to network to API's, can do it just with a POJO in your back end that connects to an API.  You might download JBoss/WildFly if you need an app server backend, it;s J2EE.  If you dont need J2EE, you could just use tomcat.  In either you could have a servlet instead of a Pojo that the Node.js front end could connect to for accessing the API.  Python is getting popular, but IMHO - If you're still on the Java track stay on it and play with Python as you go here and there to increase skill. If you really want a breakdown of frameworks I can give an answer. GL!